# Drupal 7 - multilingual comments

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-comments

I have a multilingual Drupal 7 site with i18n and Entity translation enabled. Node fields translation works perfectly, but there is something wrong with comments.
I enabled translation of comment body field. The problem is that comments are only displayed on native language version of the node . When I switch to foreign language, the node fields are translated, but comments are not shown at all (even those, which language matches the foreign language). I checked 'comment' table and it seems to be okay, the language field is populated.

Why are comments hidden on translated versions of nodes? Anyone has a clue?

Thanks for help!

Comment: check the view of "Recent comments", enable it, and in filter section, add a language filter with current user language. i didn't try, not sure it works.

Comment: It probably will, but it means I need to modify all templates to hide original comments, rewrite output of the Recent comments, so it matches the original markup and design. This sounds a bit complicated.

Is there any way to make the original comments list work?

Comment: It is a usual skill to overridden the default view by using view module. You can duplicate the "gary" view "Recent comments" to a new view. You may have to add a language filter to show up the translated contents. Just a few clicks.

Comment: If above method not work. The worst case you have to find out which sql statement is select out the comments. You have to debug the sql statement and add a condition (see the sql api of drupal 7) with current language. search Global $language how to get the current language code. The node table in database has a language column to identify the language of a node . By default "und" is the lan code for your site's default language.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem? I have the same issue now. I started to trace where the comments disappearing in the comments module's data chain, but it seems that the comment_get_thread() which queries the comments to the nodes did not give back the comment ids. In this function there is a tagged query: if you remove the 'node_access' tag from the queries in this function, the problem disappers, so i think there is a bad query alteration somewhere in the internationalization module but i didnt had time to find it yet.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
admin/config/regional/i18n/select
```

And uncheck the *"Content to filter by language"* options.